# Clearing Server cache so that Flash gallery will update itself with new images

Tags: flash, caching, magento, gallery

I'm new in magento, I have a website http://www.theartworkgallery24.com/stage/, there is a flash gallery, every time I have to clear magento cache and browser cache to display my new images but now I've made few changes in swf file that before the smaller bars are not left aligned now there are both. In my local system the new swf file shows exact number of images in the smaller bars but in server they are not showing in full numbers.

I don't know what to do as I've cleared every cache that I can. I've read some where that put version number in your swf file so that brower can check if its new then it will download new but in magento how to do that. As the swf file contents are in cms pages home page content and they have done as :

```
<script src="{{skin url='js/flashobject.js'}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="flashcontent"
class="a-center"><a
href="http://www.adobe.com/go/EN_US-H-GET-FLASH">
<img
src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_adobe_flash_player.png"
alt="" /></a></div> <script
type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
//var fo = new FlashObject("{{skin url='flash/v8_header_v8.swf'}}?xmlUrl={{skin
//url='flash/xml/'}}&picUrl={{skin url='flash/pic/'}}", "mymovie", "980", "639", "7","#0C0C0C");
//fo.addParam("quality", "high");
//fo.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
//fo.addParam("scale", "showall");
//fo.addParam("allowFullScreen", "false");
//fo.addParam("salign", "tl");
//fo.write("flashcontent");
// ]]></script>
```

so tell me how to version the swf file and how to clear cache.

Any idea will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the flash movie is given in `{{skin url='flash/v8_header_v8.swf'}}` so that must be the bit you need to change to match the new SWF file.